# How to scroll in the yocto devshell?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

How to scroll up/down in the yocto devshell (started with `bitbake -c devshell my-recipe`)?

Scrolling with the mouse is scrolling through the command history instead of through the terminal. Using <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>page up</kbd> simply prints `~2` (as in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1331658/why-cant-i-scroll-in-the-terminal)). Using `reset` doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yocto devshell uses a tmux environment (as shown by the output of `ps -a`):

```
sh-5.0# ps -a
PID TTY          TIME CMD
 29 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo
 30 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 60 pts/0    00:00:00 KnottyUI
186 pts/0    00:00:00 tmux: client
189 pts/1    00:00:00 sh
200 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

You can scroll down using tmux shortcuts (see this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux) for details), for instance using:

> <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd> then <kbd>[</kbd> then you can use your normal
> navigation keys to scroll around (eg. <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or
> <kbd>PgDn</kbd>). Press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit scroll mode..